# Identifying phycobiliprotein based on wavelength

Tags: spectroscopy, photochemistry, spectrophotometry

I have the absorption spectrum of a specific phycobiliprotein. Its maximum wavelength is 620.6 (nm),this is the only data I have. How can I know what type of phycobiliprotein it is?

Comment: Did you try looking it up? Many vendors sell these things and have spectral data available. For instance: http://www.interchim.fr/ft/2/28310A.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Its maximum wavelength is 620.6 (nm)

I'm afraid that this is pretty much a link-only answer, but based on   *Spectroscopic Properties of C-Phycocyanin and of Its $\alpha$ and $\beta$ Subunits*, published in *J. Biol. Chem.*, **1973**, *248*, 5679-5685 ([PDF](http://www.jbc.org/content/248/16/5679.full.pdf)) there's a good chance that the phycobiliprotein is **C-Phycocyanin**.